# Android room migration null error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

When i'm doing migration on Android from old sqlite way to Room i need to use "INTEGER NOT NULL" to compile.
The problem is that when migration is happening you are inserting NULL field in the new table with "NOT NULL" parameters and I'm getting error

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: note.notification_state (code 1299)

Edit:

```
11-29 22:52:58.891 14605-14630/com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
                                                                            Process: com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes, PID: 14605
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle note(com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes.repository.db.Note).
                                                                             Expected:
                                                                            TableInfo{name='note', columns={notification_date=Column{name='notification_date', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, priority=Column{name='priority', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, notification_state=Column{name='notification_state', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, created_date=Column{name='created_date', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
                                                                             Found:
                                                                            TableInfo{name='note', columns={notification_date=Column{name='notification_date', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, priority=Column{name='priority', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, notification_state=Column{name='notification_state', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, created_date=Column{name='created_date', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
                                                                                at com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes.repository.db.NoteDatabase_Impl$1.validateMigration(NoteDatabase_Impl.java:70)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:75)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:193)
                                                                                at com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes.repository.db.NoteDao_Impl$5.compute(NoteDao_Impl.java:195)
                                                                                at com.aleksandarvasilevski.notes.repository.db.NoteDao_Impl$5.compute(NoteDao_Impl.java:181)
                                                                                at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:87)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Code:

`@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 3)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE note (id INTEGER NOT NULL, title TEXT, description TEXT, created_date TEXT, notification_date TEXT, notification_state INTEGER, priority INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id))");


        database.execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO note (id, title, description, created_date) SELECT _ID, title, description, date FROM notes");

    }
};`
```

Comment: If you want `INTEGER NOT NULL`, you will not be able to store a `null` value in that column. That is not specific to Room. If your existing database allows `null` values for that column, either do not make it `NOT NULL` or figure out what sort of conversion you want to do to the existing `null` values.

Comment: The problem is that the integer must be NOT NULL or i'm getting compile time error .

Comment: Please edit your question and post a [mcve] showing your compile-time error and the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok i got it working, if anyone have the same problem just use NOT NULL DEFAULT 0(or other number).

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 3)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE note (id INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    "title TEXT, description TEXT, created_date TEXT, notification_date TEXT, " +
                    "notification_state INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                    "priority INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(id))");
            
            database.execSQL(
                    "INSERT INTO note (id, title, description, created_date) " +
                    "SELECT _ID, title, description, date FROM notes");
            
        }
    };
    
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Migration code:

```
class Migration1To2: Migration(1, 2){
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ADD COLUMN 'row_to modify' INTEGER NOT NULL **DEFAULT 1"**)
    }
}
```

---

```
 Dao Entity add **defaultValue = "1"**:
 @ColumnInfo( name="row_to modify", defaultValue = "1")
    var row_to modify: Int
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#kotlin) seems to be the Google Developers documentation. But.. why have you chosen Kotlin?